# How can you have any number of options in Streamlit?

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

How can you have any number of options in Streamlit?

If you want to be able to have a dataframe that reads data that may change depending on the document it reads, how can you have code in streamlit to fit that?

```
all_data = pd.read_excel(upload)
columns = list(all_data.columns)
for i in columns:
  st.checkbox(i)

for i in columns:
  if i:
    st.write('successful')
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have? What output are you getting? What are you expecting to get?

Comment: Very unspecific questions, let us know what exactly you want to achieve using what kind of data. Regarding pd.read_excel, you can specify sheet_name=None to read all Excel sheets instead of only the first one.

Comment: It writes 'successful' for every column whether it is checked or not